# Predict the behaviour of this system involving magnets oscillating on springs through connected coils

Tags: electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator, spring, electromagnetic-induction, resonance

I came across an interesting problem recently and started to think about the situation in more detail. Here is the setup:

*Identical bar magnets are suspended from identical springs, with the North pole 
of each magnet inside a coil of wire as shown. The two coils have the same 
number of turns and are connected together with conducting leads of negligible 
resistance.*

[image: image of the problem setup]

*Magnet A is displaced so that it oscillates vertically. The North pole of magnet A 
moves into and out of the coil of wire with simple harmonic motion. As this motion 
continues, magnet B starts to oscillate.*

I see that there will be an alternating emf in the circuit due to Faraday's law and this will create a force acting on magnet B with the same frequency causing resonance, which is why the amplitude of B starts to increase. But what will happen after this? There will now be effects from both magnets which is too much for me to think about at once. I can understand that magnet A's amplitude of oscillation will have to decrease as B's increases from conservation of energy, but after that..?

Would there be a constant phase difference/relationship between the oscillations? What happens to the net emf in the leads? What is the long term behaviour of this system if left to itself (assuming no air resistance)?

What I am looking for is a description of the behaviour of this system, either qualitative **or** with more detailed mathematical modelling (I have been unable to find the relevant equations to model this using DEs). Any insight into this is much appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz's_law is the key to the behaviour of this system.